# Getting these error while excuting the Project in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I have installed Cocos2d-x-2.2.5, ADT in my D:/ drive and NDK, Cygwin in C:/ drive also set the environment for ANDROID_NDK_PATH: C:\Users\d\Documents\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r8d, COCOS2DX_ROOT: D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-3.2, NDK_ROOT: C:\android-ndk-r10, cygwin PATH: C:\cygwin\bin

I am creating one project in Cocos2d-x and getting these error while executing this via ./build_native.sh command on **cygwin**.

```
D:/Cocos2D-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/CocosGame/proj.android/../../../extensions/CocoStudio/Reader/WidgetReader/LabelReader/LabelReader.cpp:54:9: error: 'transform' is not a member of 'std'
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10/build/core/build-binary.mk:449: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/CocoStudio/Reader/WidgetReader/LabelReader/LabelReader.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/CocoStudio/Reader/WidgetReader/LabelReader/LabelReader.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/Cocos2D-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/CocosGame/proj.android'
```

Answer (score 3):

add `#include <algorithm>` to extensions\CocoStudio\Reader\WidgetReader\LabelReader\LabelReader.cpp